# VisualStudio 2019 Performance Profiler showing code as [Unwalkable]

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to profile an ASP.NET web service on my machine under IISExpress that has an execution stack of

1. c# for the entrance point to the web service, which calls
2. c++/cli middleware, which calls
3. native c++ for the bulk of the execution, which calls
4. c++/cli & c# for some extra plug-in services that provide a Data Access Layer to the native c++ layer

This is all written in Visual Studio 2019 (C# and C++)

I am trying to profile this in Visual Studio 2019 by running IISExpress and using the Analyze / Performance Profiler to attach to the running process.

I can run my program and execute a http request (exercising my execution stack) successfully, but the profiler will only show

- iisexpress
- [Unwalkable]

as the two function names that are executed.

Does anybody have experience with getting the Performance Profiler to provide good output in similar circumstances?

I'm also open to other profilers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm getting a lot of value out of Microsoft's free PerfView https://github.com/microsoft/perfview/. Much more functional than any other profiler I tried.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same thing when trying to profile my desktop application. I had to run it in administrative mode. Then it worked as it should.